# How to access a hdf5 file (or any file) efficiently

Tags: python, hdf5

I have a hdf5 file that contains about 10 databases that I need across my project in various places (different modules).

At the moment I use a simple function that will give me the database that I want:

```
def get_hdf5_dataframe(dataframe_name: str) -> pd.DataFrame:
    db = pd.HDFStore("/database.h5")
    df = db[dataframe_name]
    db.close() # needs to be closed every time I access it

    return df
```

However, this is not efficient as the program will have to load the file every time.

If I use `lru_cache` decorator then the program will load the file 10 times for each database.

What will be an efficient way to get the databases by loading the file only once and make sure I close the hdf5 file after reading it.

Comment: why not just use `pd.HDFStore` directly?

Comment: @avigil what do you mean? every time I need it?

Comment: it already functions as a [context manager](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/8791) so you can use the `with` syntax to open and close. If you are using it across multiple locations maybe not so practical

Answer (score 1):

You could store the opened file as a global:

```
db = None

def get_hdf5_dataframe(dataframe_name: str) -> pd.DataFrame:
    global db
    if db is None:
        db = pd.HDFStore("/database.h5")
    df = db[dataframe_name]

    return df
```

This will only open it once on first access (although the file will stay open for the life of your program). Use globals with caution though- they can make life difficult if overused.

Comment: thanks. the issue with this is that if I have an error in my program then I'll have to go and manually close the hdf5 file. make life a bit difficult while developing...

Comment: you would only need to manually close in the cases where there might be pending writes, but hopefully you have those places in the code properly isolated! :)